# backbone.history.naviguate trigger router staying on the same page

Tags: backbone.js

My problem is pretty simple.

I start on /app, when I click on some button I trigger /report with 
    Backbone.history.navigate('report',{trigger: true, replace: true});

Then I'm on /report page. No problem.

I have the same button on /report and I would like to trigger router route "report" when i click on it. It seems it's not working because I'm already on the asked page.

Any idea how I should proceed ?

thanks a lot

Comment: There is a simple check there  - `if (this.fragment === fragment) return;`. Maybe you need to fire some event and catch it in another place and then just do what you want?

Comment: I would have a listener on the button you're clicking on to "re-render" the page.  Like what Vahan said, Backbone does not fire event when the hash fragment is the same.

Comment: If you must... you can do this 
      window.onhashchange = function() {

      };

Answer (score 1):

`Backbone.history.navigate('report',{trigger: true, replace: true});`

You should not be using this to render/reload your application views.This is not recommended.

Rather you should have a controller object (a js object) which extends `Backbone.Events`

Define a callback for the for the route "/report" as follows:

```
var MyAppBus = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);
MyAppBus.on("report",function(payLoad){
    // 1.Load the data
    // 2.Create an instance of the view passing the loaded data.
    // (In your case, you could also pass an instance of the view in the payload 
    // and update the data alone in the view instance.)
    // 3.Render the view.
    // 4.Call the router navigate function with trigger set to false to  
    //   update the url on a need basis. 
});
```

Now, in the `event/router callback`  you can do something like this:

```
MyAppBus.trigger("report",payLoad);
```

Where payLoad in the event callback could be:

```
var payLoad = {};
payLoad.view = viewInstance;
```